# constructor parameter injection in structuremap for runtime inputs

Tags: .net, ioc-container, structuremap

I am uisng the following  code to initialize my SM container. The abelow code works fine. But now i have requirement that needs to pass the different culture name when creating the CultureInfo instance. In short, i want to pass some input to GetCultureName() method at runtime. Is this valid use of SM or i should directly instantiate the CultureInfo in my code with appropriate culturename.

```
    public static IContainer Initialize()
    {
        ObjectFactory.Initialize(x =>
                    {
                        x.Scan(scan =>
                                {
                                    scan.TheCallingAssembly();
                                    scan.WithDefaultConventions();
                                });

                        x.For<ICultureInfoProvider>()
                          .Use<DummyCultureInfoProvider>();

                        x.For<IDocumentService>().Use<DummyDocumentService>()
                          .Ctor<CultureInfo>("cultureInfo")
                          .Is(i => new CultureInfo(i.GetInstance<ICultureInfoProvider>().GetCultureName()));
                    });
        return ObjectFactory.Container;
    }
```